# Not mocking methods, instead calls original methods (mockito)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

This class I want to test..

```
public class AddNumbers {

    public int add(int a, int b){

        checkNumbers checkobj=new checkNumbers();

        boolean flg = checkobj.check(a, b);

        if(flg == true){

            return a+b;
        }else{

            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the unit test case...

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AddNumbersTest {

    @Mock
    checkNumbers checkobj;

    @InjectMocks
    AddNumbers addobj = new AddNumbers();


    @Test
    public void testAdd1(){

        int a=10;
        int b=5;

        Mockito.when(checkobj.check(a, b)).thenReturn(true);
        assertEquals(addobj.add(a,b),15);

    }
}
```

When I running this test case, it calls original method of `checkNumbers` class instead calling mocked one. I get to know this by putting `Sysout` in `checkNumbers.check()` method.

Can anyone highlight, where I m doing the mistake.

Comment: `checkobj` is being created in the method under test. you will need to inject it to be able to manipulate its behavior when testing

Comment: Mocking objects created in a SUT is IMO the single biggest limitation of mockito. Use jmockit or powerMock or checkout the offical mockito way of handling this. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkNumbers` is created *inside* the `add` method ...

```
checkNumbers checkobj=new checkNumbers();
```

The Mockito injection feature (`@InjectMocks`) cannot populate this for you.

In order for Mockito to set `checkNumbers` to a mock you'll need to allow it to be injected.

For example: move it out of `add()` and declare it as a class member:

```
private checkNumbers checkobj;

public int add(int a, int b){
    boolean flg = checkobj.check(a, b);

    if(flg == true){

        return a+b;
    }else{

        return 0;
    }
}
```

When instructed by the `@InjectMocks` annotation Mockito will try to inject mocks by one of (in this order):

1. Constructor injection
2. Setter injection
3. Property injection

If you declare `checkNumbers` as a class member then Mockito will inject is as per #3 above. Alternatively, you could declare a constructor like so ...

```
private checkNumbers checkobj;

public AddNumbers(checkNumbers checkobj) {
    this.checkobj = checkobj;
}
```

... and Mockito will inject the mock instance as per #1 above.

This would have the benefit of making your class explicit about any other classes it needs at *construction time* and could allow you to swap in different implementations of `checkNumbers` thereby facilitating the composition of different forms of `AddNumbers`.

More details [in the Mockito docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html).

Comment: Thanks @glytching ! , I have just started working with mockito and was not much aware of the basics, I went through the Doc link you given and got the basics clear. I have implemented it using field injection and its working. Thanks once again !!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer of @glytching is absolutely correct.

Here is other possible solution with overridden getter method.

```
public class AddNumbers {
    // This is new method to return a new instance of checkNumbers.
    checkNumbers getCheckNumbers() {
        return new checkNumbers();
    }

    public int add(int a, int b){
        checkNumbers checkobj = getCheckNumbers();
        // do what you need
    }
}
```

You test has overridden getCheckNumbers():

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AddNumbersTest {
    @Mock
    checkNumbers checkobj;

    @InjectMocks
    AddNumbers addobj = new AddNumbers() {
        @Override
        checkNumbers getCheckNumbers() {
            return checkobj;
        }
    };


    @Test
    public void testAdd1(){
        int a=10;
        int b=5;

        Mockito.when(checkobj.check(a, b)).thenReturn(true);
        assertEquals(addobj.add(a,b),15);
    }
}
```

Couple general remarks regarding your code:

- Name a class starting by capital letter: `CheckNumbers`.
- Name variables by full names: `flg` -> `flag`.
- `if(flg == true)` can be simplified to `if(flg)`
- `if/esle` construction can be simplified to one line solution: `return flag ?
  a + b : 0`
- Avoid magic numbers in test names: `testAdd1` -> `addShouldSumTwoGivenIntegers()`.

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro, now onward,  I will try to follow  the best coding practices .